# Routing Resources Doesn't Set up Routing Properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, form-helpers

Normally I would expect `resources` to set the routes where

```
/groups/:id
```

However, when I call `rake routes` I get

```
GET    /groups(.:format) groups#show
```

Also, whenever I use the view helper method `groups_path(group.id)` it provides the url link as

```
/groups.1
```

Finally in my routing file

```
resource :groups
```

This is the case for edit, update, and destroy actions as well. Finally, it doesn't produce an index action. I have to create that after I write the resources method. What's wrong and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pluralize that resource:

```
resources :groups
```

Comment: Such a noob mistake. Thanks.

Comment: no problem, if i hadn't seen it before i would also be wondering what the.. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
resources :groups
```

instead of

```
resource :groups
```